# Calling or Passing Optional Parameters to Function

Tags: python

I have 3 parameters and I wanted to make 2 of them optional.  How should I call the function with the middle parameter missing?

It's a newbie question but I couldn't find any details on making 2 parameters optional without explicitly typing "None" for the optional parameter.

**Example:**

```
>>> def add (something, system = None, owner = None):
    if system is None:
        print (something)
    else:
        print ('System is not none.')


>>> 
>>> add ('First parameter', None, 'John Doe')
First parameter

>>> add ('First parameter', 'Second paremter')
System is not none.

>>> add ('First parameter', , 'John Doe')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> add ('First parameter')
First parameter
```

Comment: How could python know  what arg `'Second parameter'` is?

Comment: Hoping it would know by calling (something, , 'John Doe') where the space between the 2 commas denote a "None".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the name of the default parameter

```
add ('First parameter', owner =  'John Doe')
```

Demo

```
>>> add ('First parameter', owner =  'John Doe')
First parameter
```

Comment: I guess that would work.  I was hoping to pass it without the "owner =".

Comment: @dreamzboy Nope. You can't do that :( It is because Python is dynamically typed so the interpreter gets confused as to which parameter the argument should go to.

Comment: How about if it's actually a program and not ran inside interpreter?  Would I call it differently?  I tested outside of the interpreter and it still has the same result.

Comment: @dreamzboy Naw. It is the same way everywhere. I included the REPL part so that you can clearly differentiate between the input and output.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess it doesn't require much work assigning the variable to system.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the second parameter as empty instead passing none

example:

```
add('First parameter','','John Doe')
System is not none.
```

Now i am passing second paramter system as empty